# Understanding Postfix Mail Log

Tags: postfix, email-server, hacking

Recently I checked my mail log and found a lot of messages like this (some cipher text have been truncated):

```
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: connect from unknown[176.103.49.30]
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: setting up TLS connection from unknown[176.103.49.30]
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: unknown[176.103.49.30]: TLS cipher list "ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C0] (11 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C0] (11 bytes => 11 (0xB))
(some cipher text)
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: 0085 - <SPACES/NULLS>
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client hello B
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write certificate A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: write to 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD69108DE80] (1030 bytes => 1030 (0x406))
(some cipher text)
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: 0403 - <SPACES/NULLS>
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: 0000 16 03 03 01 06                                   .....
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C8] (262 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C8] (262 bytes => 262 (0x106))
(some cipher text)
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client key exchange A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read finished A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write finished A
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: write to 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD69108DE80] (47 bytes => 47 (0x2F))
(some cipher text)
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Feb 23 11:57:42 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[176.103.49.30]: TLSv1.2 with cipher RC4-SHA (128/128 bits)
Feb 23 11:57:43 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Read 16 chars: EHLO localhost??
Feb 23 11:57:43 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Write 158 chars: 250-mail.(domain).com??250-PIPELINING??250
Feb 23 11:57:43 postfix/smtpd[32451]: write to 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD691088A13] (183 bytes => 183 (0xB7))
(some cipher text)
Feb 23 11:57:43 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Read 45 chars: AUTH PLAIN AGFkbWluQGZpcGljay5jb20Ad2lsb
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: warning: unknown[176.103.49.30]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed: 
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Write 42 chars: 435 4.7.8 Error: authentication failed: 
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: write to 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD691088A13] (67 bytes => 67 (0x43))
(some cipher text)
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Read 3 chars: *??
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: Write 41 chars: 402 4.5.2 Error: command not recognized?
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: write to 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD691088A13] (66 bytes => 66 (0x42))
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: 0000 17 03 03 00 1a                                   .....
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C8] (26 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Feb 23 11:57:45 postfix/smtpd[32451]: read from 7FD690FE02C0 [7FD6910804C8] (26 bytes => 26 (0x1A))
```

What is the meaning of these messages? Did someone try to hack my email account?

Also, what is the appropriate action for this situation?

Comment: Did you accidentally increase the value of `smtpd_tls_loglevel`? [The default value is 0](http://www.postfix.org/TLS_README.html).

Comment: Yes, it seems someone increased `smtpd_tls_loglevel` value. Thanks for the reminder, mas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like someone one may be trying to brute force your password.   Try doing a base64 decode of the value(s) after `AUTH PLAIN`.  These should allow you to determine if they are using valid credentials.

It is likely they are starting the TLS connection in order to get access to the AUTH command which is usually not available on unencrypted connections.

It would be appropriate to blacklist the source IP at the firewall for a period of time.  There are tools like `fail2ban` which can monitor your logs and take action automatically.

If you don't need external (Internet) access to the mail server, you may want to disable StartTLS and/or AUTH.  I only enable AUTH on the Submission port (587), although I don't know how to configure that in Postfix.