# Understanding Postfix Mail Log (Part II)

Tags: postfix, email-server, hacking, smtpd

There are several logs like below in my Postfix mail log:

```
Mar  9 06:01:10 postfix/smtpd[23043]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Mar  9 06:01:10 postfix/smtpd[23043]: connect from mlxmail4.icicibank.com[203.27.235.122]
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: setting up TLS connection from mlxmail4.icicibank.com[203.27.235.122]
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: mlxmail4.icicibank.com[203.27.235.122]: TLS cipher list "ALL:+RC4:@STRENGTH"
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:before/accept initialization
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C0] (11 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C0] (11 bytes => 11 (0xB))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0000 16 03 01 02 00 01 00 01|fc 03 03                 ........ ...
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4CE] (506 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4CE] (506 bytes => 506 (0x1FA))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0128 - <SPACES/NULLS>
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client hello B
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server hello A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write certificate A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write key exchange A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write server done A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: write to 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4CBE80] (1567 bytes => 1567 (0x61F))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 061c - <SPACES/NULLS>
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (134 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (134 bytes => 134 (0x86))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read client key exchange A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0000 14 03 03 00 01                                   .....
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (1 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (1 bytes => 1 (0x1))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0000 01                                               .
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0000 16 03 03 00 28                                   ....(
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (40 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (40 bytes => 40 (0x28))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 read finished A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write change cipher spec A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 write finished A
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: write to 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4CBE80] (51 bytes => 51 (0x33))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0030 d1 82 cb                                         ...
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: SSL_accept:SSLv3 flush data
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: Anonymous TLS connection established from mlxmail4.icicibank.com[203.27.235.122]: TLSv1.2 with cipher DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Mar  9 06:01:11 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => 5 (0x5))
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: 0000 17 03 03 00 35                                   ....5
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (53 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C8] (53 bytes => 53 (0x35))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: Read 29 chars: EHLO mlxmail4.icicibank.com??
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: Write 158 chars: 250-mail.xxx.com??250-PIPELINING??250
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: write to 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4C6A13] (187 bytes => 187 (0xBB))
(some cipher text)
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))
```

What did mlxmail4.icicibank.com try to do? Did it want to send spam emails to my email account?

Comment: Who knows? All your log shows is that it connected to you. Post the rest of the log entries.

Comment: Repost [comment](http://serverfault.com/questions/672635/understanding-postfix-mail-log#comment823270_672635): "Have you accidentally increased the value of `smtpd_tls_loglevel`? Consider to set it to 0. Use this level if you want debug something, don't turn it on in daily production"

Comment: @MichaelHampton The rest of log entries doesn't seem to be related to this one. I could see the other IPs tried to initialize connections (and failed), but mlxmail4.icicibank.com always repeated connections like above.

Comment: @masegaloeh The `smtpd_tls_loglevel` was set to 4 several weeks ago and I set it 1 now (thanks to your reminder) because I don't want to completely disable logging activity.

Comment: @masegaloeh If you want to see the SMTP conversation of a TLS encrypted connection, [you pretty much need this](http://serverfault.com/a/419829/126632). As you can see it's extremely verbose but sometimes nothing else will do.

Comment: @rei, that isn't **complete** log data. You need post all lines until maillog says the client `mlxmail4.icicibank.com` was *disconnected*.

Comment: @masegaloeh After the lines above, I only saw statistics: max connection rate, max connection count, and cache size. No message that mentioned mlxmail4.icicibank.com was disconnected after that.

Comment: What's the output of `grep 'postfix/smtpd[23043]' maillog`?

Comment: @masegaloeh For 23043, that's exactly like the one that I posted above. Nothing else after `read from 7FE9DE41E2C0 [7FE9DE4BE4C3] (5 bytes => -1 (0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF))`

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. If there are no activity, [postfix should timeout](http://postfix.1071664.n5.nabble.com/timeout-after-ehlo-tp67041p67052.html) after [5 minutes of inactivity (by default)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_timeout). Try to view some logs around between 06:01:12 and 06:06:12

Comment: @masegaloeh The last line of that log is at 06:04:33, i.e. `statistics: max cache size 1 at Mar 9 06:01:10`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based of your maillog and discussion in the [comment above](https://serverfault.com/questions/675721/understanding-postfix-mail-log-part-ii#comment828310_675721), looks like the SMTP client mlxmail4.icicibank.com was **misbehaving**. It doesn't respond after postfix EHLO reply

```
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: Read 29 chars: EHLO mlxmail4.icicibank.com??
Mar  9 06:01:12 postfix/smtpd[23043]: Write 158 chars: 250-mail.xxx.com??250-PIPELINING??250
```

> ***Should I pay attention with this strange behaviour?***

Unless another client have the same symptom, then you have nothing to worry about. It isn't your postfix fault.

> What did mlxmail4.icicibank.com try to do? Did it want to send spam emails to my email account?

**Dunno**. It hung up after when SMTP wasn't finished. But unlike [your previous logs](https://serverfault.com/questions/672635/understanding-postfix-mail-log?lq=1), no AUTH attempt from mlxmail4.icicibank.com. So, it's too early to conclude that this client wants to send email to your server.

Spam activity can be detected by `grep`-ping postfix statistic from `anvil` daemon. spammer tends to do mass emailing in short time.